# How do simulacrums being completely subservient to their creators interact with wish?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, magic, wish, simulacrum

Say you went down the cheese route and have an simulacrum of an Efreeti, and you make him grant you a wish and you wish for something so cheesy the DM tries to twist your words because of this lead nugget in the text of wish.

> You may try to use a wish to produce greater effects than these, but doing so is dangerous. (The wish may pervert your intent into a literal but undesirable fulfillment or only a partial fulfillment, at the GM’s discretion.)

How does this interact with the simulacrum being underneath the creators "absolute control"?

> At all times, the simulacrum remains under your absolute command. No special telepathic link exists, so command must be exercised in some other manner.

Could you command it to not try to twist your words or would that be superseded by the spell itself doing the "twisting" of your words?
Yeah I know that DM fiat supersedes all that and that things like these are a great way to anger your DM but RAW how do these two features interact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There is no interaction

Regardless of if its a spellcaster, simulacrum, or real [Efreet](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Efreeti), the effect of Wish is bound by its own rules. Notably, nothing about the Wish spell says anything about the words being specifically important.

Even if the caster has nothing but good intentions and says the words exactly how they want, the spell leaves it open that the magic forces altering reality will act as they were going to (read: how the GM wants).